# История посещения страниц на сайте

Tags: php

Доброго времени.

Расскажите мне, господа, как можно узнать средствами PHP (или другими) историю перемещения посетителя сайта по страницам сайта, наподобие Яндекс Метрики, т.е. например зашёл юзер на главную, перешёл в раздел1, перешёл в раздел2 и т.д. Как эту информацию получить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создать сессию.
2. Каждое действие записывать в базу (например, по запрошенному урлу и реферреру), привязывая к сессии. Можно использовать связку Реферрер и Запрошенный урл, что не является самым хорошим решением, некоторые прокси эту информацию не выдают. Можно фиксировать его положение внутри системы, реализация от системы зависит - и это самое правильное решение.
3. Для просмотра делать выборку сессий и действий, упорядочивая либо по дате, либо по id

Comment: Каждое действие в базу записывать - не кашерно.

Comment: :-))) хорошо, записывайте только те действия, которые считаете нужными. Но нужно понимать, что записываться должны все его перемещения по сайту, в противном случае цепочка неполная будет. Делается это просто: человек запросил страницу, в том месте кода, где идёт её загрузка, можно вставить еще 1 запрос к базе, который сделает INSERT с всей необходимой информацией, например, урлом, названием страницы, датой и временем посещения, id сессии.

Comment: А ви таки не бойтесь, писать все в файл - еще менее кошерно, а писать блоками (по 5 страниц) - потеря данных, что вообще от шайтана.